# a simple compare of vec4.x > 5

Tags: three.js, glsl, glsles

I cannot compile the following fragment shader:

```
uniform vec3 color;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
  vec4 texel = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );
  vec3 luma = vec3( 0.299, 0.587, 0.114 );
  float v = dot( texel.xyz, luma );
  if (texel.x > 5)
    gl_FragColor = vec4( v * color, texel.w );
  else
    gl_FragColor = texel;
}
```

If I change (texel.x > 5) to (1 > 5) it works fine. But somehow texel.x causes a compile error. Does anyone see an obvious problem with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`texel.x` is a *float*, `5` is an *int*, you can't compare both directly.

Try to write `5.0` instead:

```
if (texel.x > 5.0)
```

Comment: I did not know that! you learn something new everyday. thank you

Comment: GLSL in full OpenGL does implicit conversions. So there, the original code would be legal. In OpenGL ES, there are no implicit conversions for these operators.